# Macro #define function syntax got "Expected expression before '{' token."

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using `#define` to define a set of parameters so that I could just call the defined name in the `main()` later. However, I got "`expected expression before '{' token`" in line 1. I wonder whether my syntax is wrong.

```
#define ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE {                                     \
  .properties.type = BLE_GAP_ADV_TYPE_CONNECTABLE_SCANNABLE_UNDIRECTED, \
  .p_peer_addr = NULL,                                                  \
  .interval = APP_ADV_INTERVAL,                                         \
  .duration = APP_ADV_DURATION,                                         \
  .max_adv_evts = 0,                                                    \
  .channel_mask = 0,                                                    \
  .filter_policy = BLE_GAP_ADV_FP_ANY,                                  \
  .primary_phy = BLE_GAP_PHY_1MBPS,                                     \
  .secondary_phy = 0,                                                   \
  .set_id = 0,                                                          \
  .scan_req_notification = 0                                            \
}
```

From a comment:

> I have a calling function:
>
> ```
> m_adv_handle = advertising_init_common(&m_adv_data, ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);
> ```
>
> After editing the code, in this calling line, I have a error of "`expected expression before ')' token`".

Updated:

```
 typedef struct
{
 ble_gap_adv_properties_t properties;              
 ble_gap_addr_t const    *p_peer_addr;             
 uint32_t                 interval;                
 uint16_t                 duration;                
 uint8_t                  max_adv_evts;            
 ble_gap_ch_mask_t        channel_mask;            
 uint8_t                  filter_policy;           
 uint8_t                  primary_phy;             
 uint8_t                  secondary_phy;          
 uint8_t                  set_id:4;                
 uint8_t                  scan_req_notification:1; 
 }ble_gap_adv_params_t; //******this being declare in another .h file

 #define ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE (ble_gap_adv_params_t) {               \
  .properties.type = BLE_GAP_ADV_TYPE_CONNECTABLE_SCANNABLE_UNDIRECTED, \
  .p_peer_addr = NULL,                                                  \
  .interval = APP_ADV_INTERVAL,                                         \
  .duration = APP_ADV_DURATION,                                         \
  .max_adv_evts = 0,                                                    \
  .channel_mask = 0,                                                    \
  .filter_policy = BLE_GAP_ADV_FP_ANY,                                  \
  .primary_phy = BLE_GAP_PHY_1MBPS,                                     \
  .secondary_phy = 0,                                                   \
  .set_id = 0,                                                          \
  .scan_req_notification = 0                                          \
 }

 static uint8_t advertising_init_common(ble_gap_adv_data_t* 
  ble_gap_adv_data, ble_gap_adv_params_t adv_params)
 {
  ret_code_t    err_code;
  ble_advdata_t advdata;
  ble_advdata_t srdata;
  uint8_t advHandle;

  ble_uuid_t adv_uuids[] = {{LBS_UUID_SERVICE, m_lbs.uuid_type}};`

  // Build and set advertising data.
   memset(&ble_gap_adv_data->adv_data, 0, sizeof(ble_gap_adv_data->adv_data));

  advdata.name_type          = BLE_ADVDATA_FULL_NAME;
  advdata.include_appearance = true;
  advdata.flags              = BLE_GAP_ADV_FLAGS_LE_ONLY_GENERAL_DISC_MODE;

  memset(&srdata, 0, sizeof(srdata));
  srdata.uuids_complete.uuid_cnt = sizeof(adv_uuids) / sizeof(adv_uuids[0]);
  srdata.uuids_complete.p_uuids  = adv_uuids;

  err_code = ble_advdata_encode(&advdata, ble_gap_adv_data->adv_data.p_data, &ble_gap_adv_data->adv_data.len);
APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

err_code = ble_advdata_encode(&srdata, ble_gap_adv_data->scan_rsp_data.p_data, &ble_gap_adv_data->scan_rsp_data.len);
APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);


// Set advertising parameters.
err_code = sd_ble_gap_adv_set_configure(&advHandle, ble_gap_adv_data, 
&adv_params);
APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
return advHandle;
}

int main()
{
 m_adv_handle = advertising_init_common(&m_adv_data, 
 ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE); //*********here i have "expected expression before ')' token message*******//
}
```

[image]

So I wonder where does I done wrongly again. Can guide me? Thank you

Comment: That's a C99 construct using designated initializer notation — it is not valid C++, even if you find a C++ compiler that accepts it.  It could also be used with a `(AppropriateType) ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE` to make a compound literal, which is also not a part of C++ (though again, you might find a C++ compiler that accepts it, provided you don't put it into pedantic "C++ only" mode).  Assume it won't work — rethink what you are doing.  Or choose the correct language — which is C, not C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You mean to say that every major C++ compiler accepts it. In fact, I'd be interested if you found one that doesn't.

Comment: @okovko A macro that isn't used isn't seen at all by the compiler (after the preprocessor), so no this is not a complete example.

Comment: @okovko: I suspect that G++ accepts it, and I'd not be surprised to find that Clang++ supports for G++ compatibility.  However, I've not explored which compilers do or do not accept it, and it remains "not part of standard C++" (but it is a part of C) — which makes it yet another area where C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: Given the information transcribed from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246949/macro-define-function-syntax-got-expected-expression-before-token#comment95318599_54247090), you would need to convert the macro into a compound literal. However, you also need to provide a declaration for `advertising_init_common()` — and you need to provide both minimal (you could use 3-6 elements instead of 11) and complete (a definition of the structure or class that you're working with), as well as the exact code and the exact error message for that code. This is what makes an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: It's always better to be friendly and helpful rather than pedantic. I don't know why you two are acting like compilers. Nobody likes compilers.

Comment: Have you identified which compiler you're using, and the platform on which you're using it?  For example, are you using MSVS on Windows?  Or G++ on Linux?  Or some other compiler and/or platform.  My suspicion is that you're using MSVS, but you can correct me on that.  You've also not shown the exact error message you get from the updated code — that could also help (it would help identify the compiler, too).  You'd be allowed to miss out all the path part of the file name being compiled if it is very long — but the base name of the file should be kept.

Comment: I'm puzzled that your `advertising_init_common()` function doesn't take either a pointer or a reference to the `ble_gap_adv_params_t` parameter.  It is OK to pass structure or class parameters by value, as you do here, but many people would only pass them by reference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, im using Segger Embedded studio ARM V3.50.

Comment: Oh — now that's one I'd not heard of before this evening!  It would be good to edit that information into the question.  The platform provides both GCC and Clang.  The [release notes](https://studio.segger.com/index.htm?https://studio.segger.com/arm_segger_studio_release_notes.htm) (I've no idea why the URL is so convoluted) indicate that the 3.50 edition comes with Clang 6.0.1 and GCC ARM Embedded Toolchain 7-2018-q2-update (which I hazard a guess is based on GCC 7.x).  You could probably run `g++ --version` to check.

Comment: What compilation options are you using?  I'm particularly interested in `-std=XXX`, and any `-Wxyzpqr` options you use, and any `-fsyzygy` options (and uninterested in `-I`, `-L`, `-l` options).

Comment: I've just tried to take your updated code, but it is uncompilable because there are so many types and defines which you've not provided.  ***PLEASE*** read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) — and provide us one.  You need to delete swathes of code that is tangential to the problem, and reduce the structures to a minimum, etc.  What's left needs to be compilable — and needs to generate the error message.  We should not have to work so hard to help you!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have no idea how do I check the compilation option that u are insterested with. I write the code in the Segger Embedded studio ARM V3.50 and compile the  code directly with it. Or would you mind guide me where should I check? Thank you.

Comment: Ouch — that makes two of us.  I don't use IDEs in general, and I've never used this one, so I've no idea what's required, or what they call it.  Compilation properties or something like that might be applicable.  OK; scratch the request for compilation parameters.  I guess the MCVE is important.  It's about to be bedtime here; I'll be offline for 8+ hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a type along with the `C99` [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

```
typedef struct conn_s { /*...*/ } conn_t;

#define ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE (conn_t){ /*...*/ }

int main() {
   conn_t conn = ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE;
}
```

Here is an [example](https://repl.it/repls/RustyDelectableLivedistro).

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion. How about calling it. I have a calling function :

m_adv_handle = advertising_init_common(&m_adv_data, ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);

After edit the code, in this calling line, i have a error of "expected expression before ')' token . Should I add (conn_t) as well when call it to run?

Comment: Making a compound literal is one way of using it.  Another is as an initializer: `conn_t conn = ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE;`.  You don't need the 'cast' notation to make it work as an initializer.

Comment: @Kathleen No. What do you get when you run `gcc -E file.cpp`?

Comment: @okovko  I got "expected expression before ';' token " message. Sorry, i'm just beginner.

Comment: @Kathleen I have a working example available for you to look at, I edited it into my answer. Make sure there is a space after `ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE` and before `(conn_t)`.

Comment: @okovko, yes, i done accordingly to your example, I have the define function exactly like yours just i have two parameters . However, I still have the same error message of " expected expression before ')' token at the line in 
`int main()` `{`
`advertising_init_common(&m_adv_data, ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);`

Comment: @Kathleen I have reproduced your error message [here](https://repl.it/repls/MarriedOurInversion). It looks like the macro is not expanding correctly. What do you get when you preprocess your source code with the `-E` flag?

Answer (score 1):

This is too big to be a comment, so it's a pseudo-answer.

Here's an approximation to an MCVE — with the significant problem that when I compile it, I don't see the error that you see.

**`arm31.cpp`**

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t    interval;
    uint16_t    duration;
    uint8_t     max_adv_evts;
    uint8_t     secondary_phy;
} ble_gap_adv_params_t;

typedef struct
{
    ble_gap_adv_params_t    adv_params;
    uint16_t                adv_program;
} ble_gap_adv_data_t;

#define ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE (ble_gap_adv_params_t) { \
        .interval = 29,                                    \
        .duration = 31,                                    \
        .max_adv_evts = 0,                                 \
        .secondary_phy = 0,                                \
}

static uint8_t advertising_init_common(ble_gap_adv_data_t *ble_gap_adv_data,
                                       ble_gap_adv_params_t adv_params)
{
    uint8_t advHandle = 19;
    ble_gap_adv_data->adv_params = adv_params;
    ble_gap_adv_data->adv_program = 31963;
    return advHandle;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ble_gap_adv_data_t m_adv_data;
    uint8_t m_adv_handle = advertising_init_common(&m_adv_data,
                                                   ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);
    std::cout
        << "handle:   " << m_adv_handle << ", "
        << "program:  " << m_adv_data.adv_program << ", "
        << "interval: " << m_adv_data.adv_params.interval << ", "
        << "duration: " << m_adv_data.adv_params.duration << ", "
        << "maxadvev: " << m_adv_data.adv_params.max_adv_evts << ", "
        << "secondph: " << m_adv_data.adv_params.secondary_phy << "\n";
}
```

#### Compilation

```
$ g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c arm31.cpp
$
```

That produces no warnings (on a Mac running macOS 10.14.2 Mojave, using a home-built G++ 8.2.0).  To get warnings, I need to use `-pedantic` too:

```
$ g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c arm31.cpp
arm31.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
arm31.cpp:18:9: error: C++ designated initializers only available with -std=c++2a or -std=gnu++2a [-Werror=pedantic]
         .interval = 29,                                          \
         ^
arm31.cpp:39:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE’
                                                    ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
arm31.cpp:19:9: error: C++ designated initializers only available with -std=c++2a or -std=gnu++2a [-Werror=pedantic]
         .duration = 31,                                          \
         ^
arm31.cpp:39:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE’
                                                    ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
arm31.cpp:20:9: error: C++ designated initializers only available with -std=c++2a or -std=gnu++2a [-Werror=pedantic]
         .max_adv_evts = 0,                                       \
         ^
arm31.cpp:39:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE’
                                                    ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
arm31.cpp:21:9: error: C++ designated initializers only available with -std=c++2a or -std=gnu++2a [-Werror=pedantic]
         .secondary_phy = 0,                                      \
         ^
arm31.cpp:39:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE’
                                                    ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
arm31.cpp:22:1: error: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals [-Werror=pedantic]
 }
 ^
arm31.cpp:39:52: note: in expansion of macro ‘ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE’
                                                    ADV_1M_LEGACY_CONNECTABLE);
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

#### Next steps

Please take this source code and compile it on your system.  Then tinker with it until it reproduces the error you're seeing.  Then post that amended code as an edit to the question.